# How to pass PFObject from a mainViewController to a detail UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipageviewcontroller, pfobject

I have searched for an answer to this without success. I want to be able to select an item in a UICollectionView and go to its detailview, a UIPageViewController scrolling three different view controllers horizontally.

The problem is that I can not figure out how to pass the data from my main view to the detail views when using UIPageViewController. I can pass it on to a normal detailViewController, but using UIPageViewController, my listItems are null when reaching pageViewController.

How do I pass the image and the label on to my page1ViewController, I guess I am missing a step in my detailPagingViewController? I am still learning, all help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the storyboard:
http://pbrd.co/1y2rdB2

In collectionViewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailPageVC"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender];
    DetailPagingViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    PFObject *object = [imagesFilesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ListItems *listItem = [[ListItems alloc] init];
    listItem.name = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
    listItem.imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
    destViewController.listItem = listItem;
}
```

}

In detailPagingViewController.h

```
@interface DetailPagingViewController : UIPageViewController
<UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) ListItems *listItem;

@end
```

detailPagingViewController.m

```
@interface DetailPagingViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *contentPageRestorationIDs;

@end


@implementation DetailPagingViewController
{
    NSArray *myViewControllers;
}

@synthesize listItem;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.delegate = self;
    self.dataSource = self;

    UIViewController *p1 = [self.storyboard
                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Page1VC"];
    UIViewController *p2 = [self.storyboard
                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Page2VC"];
    UIViewController *p3 = [self.storyboard
                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Page3VC"];

    myViewControllers = @[p1,p2,p3];

    [self setViewControllers:@[p1]
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:NO completion:nil];

}

-(UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return myViewControllers[index];
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [myViewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    --currentIndex;
    currentIndex = currentIndex % (myViewControllers.count);
    return [myViewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [myViewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    ++currentIndex;
    currentIndex = currentIndex % (myViewControllers.count);
    return [myViewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}

-(NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return myViewControllers.count;
}

-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}

@end
```

In pageViewController.h

```
@interface Page1ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *mainImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;

@property (nonatomic, strong) ListItems *listItem;

@end
```

And in pageViewController.m

```
@implementation Page1ViewController

@synthesize mainImage, listItem, nameLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    mainImage.file = listItem.imageFile;

    nameLabel.text = listItem.name;
}

@end
```

Comment: When you set up your page view controllers in DetailPagingViewController viewDidLoad simply set an 'listItem` property on each one from using self.listItem.  You will need to declare `p1` etc as 'Page1ViewController` etc rather than `UIViewController`

Comment: Thank you! Now I can can set the label, but unfortunately not the image, neither on the first or second viewController. I changed UIViewController to my own viewControllers and set p1.listItem = self.listItem; in DPVC. The setup for the image view in the page1ViewController etc is exactly the same as when I was using a normal detailViewController. I do not understand why it does not work now. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Check that the IBOutlet isnt nil and make sure the image view is on screen - ie check constraints etc

Comment: That is not it unfortunately. I will post here if I find the solution...